# Spring MVC Model Attribute null

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want do add an ID to a URL in my template:

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public String index(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("provider_id", "1");

        return "dashboard";
    }
}
```

In my dashboard.html I want do display the ID.

```
<a th:href="@{'/cloudservice/' + ${provider_id}}">Show</a>
```

But the Generated URL is `/cloudservice/null`. Why isn't the 1 displayed that i put into the model?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this out and I couldn't recreate this issue, this is working perfectly fine for me. Please share the complete controller code and your dependencies here.
One wild guess, your Model class is of type org.springframework.ui.Model, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls

```
<!-- Will produce '/gtvg/order/3/details' (plus rewriting) -->
<a href="details.html" th:href="@{/order/{orderId}/details(orderId=${o.id})}">view</a>
```